# Multi Threaded App Slow to Stop

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

Utilizing Visual Studio 2010:

I have .net application that spawns hundreds of thousands of threads over the course of 14 hours everyday.  I do run the application in the IDE as "production" for now.  My question is, why is it when I pause or stop the application through the IDE interface, does it hang for 5 to 10 seconds before stopping?

I have checked:

Debug > Windows > Threads

To verify that my threads are closing before I stop the application.  (They are.  They are executing & finishing hours before I even try to stop.)

I have checked Control + Alt + Delete, to verify that the resources are not pegged.  CPU is running at 0%, and 35% of memory consumed (No fluctuations).

Unfortunately, that's about as far as I can go with trying to figure out why I have this symptom.  I have been stopping this application, and starting it every day since 2011, all because I fear that if I leave the program running for 2 days straight, that there will be a performance degradation based on what I see when I hit the stop button.

Thanks in advance for points & solutions.

Comment: "I have .net application that spawns hundreds of thousands of threads over the course of 14 hours everyday." - lolWHAT?!   "I do run the application in the IDE as "production" for now."  ah... bu.. wha... "have been stopping this application, and starting it every day since 2011" ... just never mind.

Comment: I know.  I didn't have to put that "extra information" in.  I deserve that feedback.  I am just fed up about not making it a priority.  It's my first project of this magnitude.  I have written plenty of other multi theaded applications before, but never on this scale.

Comment: I want to make it clear that there's nothing wrong with writing slightly dodgy code (or at least, that's what it smells like to me).  However, it is surprising when your concern is a 5 second delay on shutdown (which should have no appreciable effect) not the apparent serious design issues.  Consider getting the 'threads instantiated' down to a few dozen, your code running without an IDE in production, and the performance and reliability (and alerting) to the stage where you can let it run without interference.  Then worry about shut down times.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is a debug process keeping track of that huge list of threads and all their metadata could account for some of the slowdown. Furthermore, slow pausing can sometimes be due to the size of your project. While 5 to 10 seconds is extreme, I have rarely seen pausing be terribly immediate, since it has to cleanup all internal resources.

If you want to test the program for stability, I would recommend trying to pause it at several different times (6 hrs, 12 hrs, 24 hrs, ect.) and see if there is a difference. More likely it simply plateaus at a certain point in the performance, and there may not be a problem running it for 2 or more days.

If you want to test the program in the most "in the wild" conditions possible, consider running it in release mode without any pdb (and thus no debugger), but add a bit of code to throw all those thread closures into a log file (or the windows event log) and check in on performance and resource usage after the same intervals mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a whirl.  Appreciate your input.